# How to train a Word2vec Model on Faceboock Comments?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, graph, word2vec

In order to get a better accuracy for Sentiment  Analysis I'm going to train the Word2vec model on Facebook Comments instead of e.g Wikipedia. I wanted to know which points I have to consider during the gathering comments using Python and graph API.
How should I save the comments? Or other issues which are important.